# Override css for a single column in richdatatable

Tags: css, jsf

i am using jsf 1.2. css for columns of my rich:dataTable is as follows:-

```
 .cssAllColumns {
    border-right: 1px solid #A0B681;
    border-top: 1px solid #A0B728;
    border-left: 1px solid #A0B681;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A0B728;
    padding: 1px;
    }
....
<rich:dataTable value="#{employeeBean.employeeList}" ...  columnClasses="cssAllColumns"  .../>
```

I want single column to align left as follows

```
<rich:column id="employeeName" sortable="true" style="text-align:left;cellspacing=5;">
```

Its aligning single column to left and all other to center (as per requirement) but its too tightly left_aligned. i want to leave 2 to 3 char-spaces from left border. 
How that could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

i have never used rich tables but if they follow the same principles, your inline css is incorrect.

Change

```
<rich:column id="employeeName" sortable="true" style="text-align:left;cellspacing=5;">
```

to

```
<rich:column id="employeeName" sortable="true" cellspacing="5" style="text-align:left;">
```

Oh and also, if you have CSS being defined, try using the `!important` in the inline css to overwrite the classes that you have declared.

Comment: Attribute cellspacing invalid for tag column according to TLD error for your suggested answer.

Comment: @user3751492 have you tried doing this with declaring css at the top? e.g. `.Whatever {border-spacing: 10px;border-collapse: separate;}`